# Sequelize Many-to-Many Association --- SequelizeEagerLoadingError: "User is not associated to User!"

Tags: sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations

I'm attempting to create a Many-to-Many association where User is associated with itself.

When I query the N:M I get this error: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: "User is not associated to User!"

Everything looks in shape to me, but the patchy documentation makes it hard to tell what is up to date. I've scoured dozens of posts to no avail. Please help

**User Model**

```
    "use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
      userUUID: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        unique: {
          arg: true,
          msg: "Username is taken",
        },
        validate: {
          notNull: { msg: "Username must not be null" },
          notEmpty: { msg: "Username must be given" },
        },
      },
      phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        unique: {
          arg: true,
          msg: "Phone is taken",
        },
        validate: {
          notNull: { msg: "Phone must not be null" },
          notEmpty: { msg: "Phone must be given" },
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      birthday: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
      realName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: "",
      },
      bio: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: "User",
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.belongsToMany(models.User, { as: 'Sender', foreignKey: 'senderUUID', through: "Friendship" });
    User.belongsToMany(models.User, { as: 'Recevier', foreignKey: 'receiverUUID', through: "Friendship" });
  }
  return User;
};
```

**Friendship Migration**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Friendship", {
      friendshipUUID: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      senderUUID: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT,
        references: {
          model: 'User',
          key: 'userUUID',
          as: 'Sender'
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      receiverUUID: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT,
        references: {
          model: 'User',
          key: 'userUUID',
          as: 'Receiver'
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Friendship");
  }
};
```

**Relevant User Controller**

```
const getFriends = async (req, res) => {
  const userUUID = req.params.userUUID
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({
        where: { userUUID },
        include: [{
          model: User,
          as: 'Sender',
          attributes: ['username'],
          through: {
            attributes: []
          }
        }],
      });
      
      return res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Could not get friends - " + err });
    }
  };
```

**Index.js**

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: I don't see code where you register models and associations, please show it

Comment: Just included index.js

Comment: Did you check that `User.associate` was actually called? Did you check `associations` option in `User` right before executing `User.findOne`?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, how would I got about doing that?

Comment: Can you run your service in debug mode? If yes then just set a breakpoint inside `User.associate`, run in a debug mode and make sure your breakpoint hits. The same goes for the second point about `associations`. W/o debugging ou can simply add console.log in both cases

Comment: I've verified that User.associate executes, not sure how I would check the second point

Comment: just add `console.log(User.assocations)` before the line `const user = await User.findOne({`

Comment: Ok, User.associations are undefined

Comment: Can you check the same `console.log(User.associations)` after two calls `User.belongsToMany`?

Comment: Just did, associations are undefined

Comment: Did you do in inside `associate` method?